# What is the most efficient way to farm Carpenterbugs?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I got all the rest of the ingredients needed to upgrade my axe, but I'm still short by 7 Carpenterbugs. What is the most efficient way to farm these? What map should I do it on, and what route should I take to hit all the potential bug patches with a high chance to get Carpenterbugs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carpenterbugs can be found in a variety of places. The Tundra and Flooded Forest areas possess them, but the earliest you can encounter them is in the Moga Woods. Be sure to equip good gathering equipment (the starting Leather set isn't bad) as well as food buffs and head to Area 4 (the Giggi cave). Off to the side, there's an alcove with Felynxes and Melynxes. There's a bug gathering spot in the center where you can find Carpenterbugs. I've personally gathered at least 1 Carpenterbug each time when decked out properly and have received upwards of 4 in one run.

Comment: They can also be found in the Sandy Plains. Also, if we are talking anecdotal evidence of drop rates, I have had terrible luck with Area 4 in Moga Woods despite food buffs and appropriate gear (never more than one, still less than one per run over a dozen or so runs). IDK what the actual drop rates are but clearly I triggered the desire sensor.

Oh, and I believe the Deserted Island has different gather rates to freehunting in Moga Woods, but I don't know if they're better or worse in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Moga Woods/Deserted Isle and the Sandy Plains. Area 4 in Moga Woods/Deserted Isle almost always has a guaranteed Carpenterbug, but they're almost non-existent elsewhere on the map (they can be found, just don't expect them).

The Sandy Plains is probably your best bet, since each bug gather spot has a decent chance of giving a Carpenterbug. Keep an eye out for Blue ones in the Sandy Plains, I managed to get 5 of them from one. The quest Rhenoplos Rampage also has a good chance of giving you a Carpenterbug.

As for other maps I have no idea, but I've never found any in the Flooded Forest

Answer (score 0):

I have only found them in almost all the maps but they are still very rare. In the beginning I would advise to go to 3, or 4 for carpenter bugs. In 3 only the blue shiny bug spots have them(except the blue one next to the cave). And in 4 if you find the "cats hideout" you are almost sure for at least 1 carpenter bug per visit in the cat hideout. They are also in the sandy plains too anywhere with a blue shiny bug spots you may not always find them, but its unlikely

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find carpenter bugs are in the Moga Woods in area 4 in the cave where the cats' hide out is. You can usually find about 1-3 max per visit or if your lucky, you might get 4. Also expect some thunder bugs and other bugs in that cave. Also in the Sandy Plains check the caves for bugs. Only **blue shiny ones** in the Sandy Plains Caves!